# How to create the opposite to existing Regex?

Tags: regex

I have this Regex that mathes values with all same characters:

`^(.)\1+$` is true for `aaaaaa` or `33333333` but not `ssssssssR` or even `ssssssS`

I need opposite one, but nothing with `!?` helped me.

Could someone hint what regex should be not to match values all-same character values?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is `^(?!(.)\1+$).*`

Comment: Are you saying you wish the match to fail if the strings contains any character twice in a row, else the entire string is to be matched?

Comment: Yes. This works. ^(?!(.)\1+$).* . Thanks everybody for help!

Comment: You answered "yes" to my question but your regex does not do that. For example, your regex matches `abbc`, but you say the match is to fail because `b` appears twice in a row. In fact, your regex matches every string having fewer than three characters and every string having three or more characters that are not all the same. If the problem is as I stated you need a regular expression such as the following: `^(?!.*(.)\1).*`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/z5ZPrd/1/). The negative lookahead reads, "the beginning of a line cannot be followed by 0+ chars then two instances of the same character".

Comment: No, that was what I needed in fact. Thanks